# Managing document types: Where are the normal ones?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In order to allow creating links to other Sharepoint documents, I enabled the setting `Allow Management of Content Types` in `Advanced Settings` for the Document Library.

Now I have the following Content Types:

- Document
- Link to a Document
- Form
- Report

If I click on `Add from existing site content types` I see a lot of weird options, but nothing for Excel spreadsheets, powerpoint presentations or any of the normal things I would expect.

[image]

So now here is all I see when I click "New":

[image]

How can I Allow Management of Content Types and still have normal document types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Document" content type is what you are looking for, but out of the box it gives users a Word template. If you would like to create an Excel or PowerPoint, you could create a new content type that derives from the "Document" content type, and then upload a blank pptx or xlsx file for the template.

In short, Document encompasses all documents or files, if you want to be specific, you need to separate the content type "Document" into different content types.

Comment: That makes sense, but "Document" isn't one of the `Available Site Content Types` as in the screenshot above

Comment: That's because it's already a part of the available content types in that list/library. The drop-down list you show in the screenshot is the content types that are not yet a part of the list.

Comment: So I renamed "Document" to "Word Document", now how do I add a new one?  http://i.imgur.com/i0Cj0ag.png

Comment: I added "Allow any content type", renamed it "Excel Document", uploaded an XLS file as a template but for some reason I can't set it to show up in the New button:  http://i.imgur.com/cs0xYhT.png    http://i.imgur.com/JVnRYmR.png  http://i.imgur.com/7w90Ju7.png

Comment: For now I just renamed the Document type to "Document" and removed the template so it just says "New Document" and I can pick a spreadsheet or whatever I want.  Not ideal but until I can make sense of this mess I guess it will work

Comment: You should really create three content types, One for Excel, One for Word, and One for PowerPoint. All three are content types have the parent "Document", which you can choose when creating content types. Each will have a template associated to it. Upload each template to each content type respectively. Then add each content type to the list/library of available content types.

Comment: I can't figure out where to create a content type other than what I posted above

Comment: Go to Site Settings and "Site Content Types", then create a new one. After you create three mentioned above, then you see them from the "Add from existing content types" in the list/library settings.

Comment: That's what I was missing, thanks.  I wish there was a link to this under the list of Content Types in the Document Library Properties.

Comment: It's also worth noting that these seem to be global